# Highlight ListView row without Views in it

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

I have created ListView with checkbox and textview(with custom background) in every row. 
When I click on a row, checkbox and textview get highlighted with a listview row, but I want to get highlighted only the listview row without checkbox and textview after I click on the row. Could you help me please?

This is what I want after click on a row: http://tinypic.com/r/14kfpza/5.

This is what I have after click on a row: http://tinypic.com/r/2mr5w9c/5.

Thank you

My adapter for listview:

```
public class MyAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context ctx;
    List<String> content;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_row ,objects);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.content = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
        }
        TextView desc = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String name = content.get(position);
        desc.setText(name.toString());

        return row;
    }



}
```

listview_row.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_bg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
           android:text="" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved it, with custom TextView, the setPressed method is overwritten. The same I have done with CheckBox.

```java
public class TextViewForListView extends TextView{

    public TextViewForListView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    public TextViewForListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public TextViewForListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed && (this.getParent() instanceof View) && ((View) this.getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in ur listView xml .
android:addStatesFromChildren="false"

This will not send the click events to the children of listView